# Ansible playbook for ssh keys: one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one

Tags: ansible

I'm a bit new to Ansible and trying to work out a playbook to cover several different use cases and must be missing something obvious about how to set this up because what I have so far is not working. Basically, the way I wrote the playbook, I can't use `exclusive: no` because I'm using `with_items` which I found out isn't loop aware.

The constraints for disseminating the ssh keys are like this:

- users who only ssh to one host
- users who ssh to many hosts
- users who ssh to many hosts as different users
- some users have "site" keys (work) and remote keys (home)

I have a `vars_file` defined below which assigns remote users and remote hosts to a given key. I'm not sure this is the best way to do it because I end up defining multiple hashes for the same key when a user needs to access a server as two different users; eg: developer (timmy) is deploying rails applications and uses the `passenger` account from within `capistrano` but other times he will ssh in as *timmy* to use `sudo` to restart the webserver.

Additionally, people come-and-go so when the playbook runs, it needs to first remove whatever `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is there so it can rebuild it from an updated `vars_file` where keys have been added or removed (simply appending to that file leaves old keys in place). I haven't included that portion in my snippet below because.. brevity. The part I can't get working is the `authorized_keys` bit.  Anyone have some suggestions? Maybe I totally need to redefine this whole thing using `host_vars` or `loop`?

```
ssh_keys:
      - name   : eric_site_key
        group  : systems
        pubkey : "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/eric_site.pub') }}"
        remote_users:
          - eric
        remote_hosts:
          - all

      - name   : eric_home_key
        group  : systems
        pubkey : "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/eric_homekey.pub') }}"
        remote_users:
          - eric
        remote_hosts:
          - sshgateway1
          - sshgateway2

      - name   : timmy_site_key
        group  : systems
        pubkey : "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/timmy_site.pub') }}"
        remote_users:
          - timmy
        remote_hosts:
          - sshgateway1


      - name   : timmy_site_key
        group  : systems
        pubkey : "{{ lookup('file', '../group_vars/pubkeys/timmy_site.pub') }}"
        remote_users:
          - timmy
          - passenger
        remote_hosts:
          - webserver1
          - webserver2
```

snippet from the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - ../group_vars/ssh_keys.yml


    - name: setup ssh pub key
      when: inventory_hostname in item.0.remote_hosts or 'all' in item.0.remote_hosts
      authorized_key:
        user   : "{{ item.1.remote_users }}" 
        state  : present
        key    : '{{ item.0.pubkey }}'
        exclusive: no
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ssh_keys }}"
        - remote_users
```

Comment: And what's wrong with this except `item.1.remote_users` should be `item.1`?

Comment: When I run it, for instance, only _eric_site.pub_ would populate `authorized_keys`. I thought it was from defining the variables incorrectly but I see now that I was trying to match `inventory_hostname` (FQDN) against the _short_ hostname (eg: _sshgateway1_). I think it is working now.  Thank you for taking time to look at it.